# Not able to access Postgresql from CMD in Windows

Tags: windows-7-x64, postgresql-8.4

I installed OpenGeo Suite 2.4.5 in windows 7. I want to access postgresql from cmd but when I trying to access it, I am getting this error:

```
    psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
         Is the server running on host "???" and accepting
         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
    could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "???" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Even I am getting same error when I tried to connect through QGIS. I think postgresql service is not listed thats why I am not able to access or connect it. Can some one please guide me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally .. found the answer. .. on CMD run: 
       `c:\ psql -p 54321 -U postgres` 
and similarly .. change port number to `54321` in QGIS to access it.